# Can't resolve 'resolve-pathname' and 'value-equal' in React.js when importing react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to make an E-commerce website using React.js but when I import **react-router-dom** it throws the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/history/esm/history.js 2:0-47      Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'resolve-pathname' in '/home/usr/my-app/node_modules/history/esm'                                                          
ERROR in ./node_modules/history/esm/history.js 3:0-37      Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'value-equal' in '/home/usr/my-app/node_modules/history/esm'

webpack compiled with 2 errors and 1 warning
```

At first it showed 17 errors but after trying for hours and installing various random packages it came down to two. Now I'm stuck and have absolutely no clue what to do next.

Here's my package.json

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-icons-kit": "^2.0.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
        "react-router": "^5.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
        /* The random packages I installed that reduced the number of errors */
        "history": "^4.10.1",
        "source-map-loader": "^4.0.1",
        "tiny-invariant": "^1.3.1",
        "tiny-warning": "^1.0.3",
        "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

Here's App.js

```
import { React } from 'react'
import { Header } from './components/Header'
import { Body } from './components/Body'
import { Footer } from './components/Footer'
import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";

/* Not only Switch, any module that I import throws the same error */

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Body />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The website seems to work perfectly fine when I comment out `import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";`

**N.B:** All the packages listed in package.json exists in the node_modules directory.
I've tried deleting the node_modules directory and re-initializeing it using `npm i`. I also tried restarting the server and `npm cache clean --force`.
None of them seems to work.

As a beginner in React, any help would be highly appreciated. <3

Comment: `npm i react-router-dom`

Comment: No, ```npm i react-router-dom``` didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work about it? Is the installation failing?

Comment: No, the packages have no problem in installation. Everything was installed properly. The problem occurs only when I include ```react-router-dom```  in any of my js files